# Using Napp Drawer Alloy Widget for TabGroup

Tags: module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

could someone please guide me on how to use Napp Drawer widget in TabGroup (i am using 3 tabs currently)?

Though I have not tried it yet but before trying it out, I want your advises. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible.

[DrawerLayout Issue](https://github.com/manumaticx/Ti.DrawerLayout/issues/32#issuecomment-111413941)

[NappDrawer Issue](https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/issues/87)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had also done a lot of research whether it is possible by any means...but I ended up by implementing ScrollableView along with the tab-like buttons which control the ScrollableView scrolling and also the scroll/scrollend events. (now my tabs are swipeable on iOS as well **:)** hehe).